# Show health numbers of allies and enemies

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there an option or possibility to show the exact number of max. and current health of enemies and allies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show as in, on screen? No.

You might be able to get some data from a combat log parser if you check your 'Combat' chat tab.

Comment: I'm not really interested that much in the log. I would like some information in combat or before combat to roughly estimate the outcome of a fight. Log evaluation would be a whole different story(like DPS comparison, min-maxing, etc.). It would even be very interesting to find out how much health pets/illusions have.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then. To assess enemies you'll need to look at their level comapred to your own. The level number on mobs will change colour depending on the level difference, from green, to white to purple.
Also pay attention to the ring around the mob. From none for regular, to bronze for veterans, silver for tough, gold for champions and purple flash for "Super-doopa", http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Monster_rank

Comment: Ok thank you anyways. But I was more about PvP. There you simply can't measure anything from pure observation, sadly.